# How to traverse nested JSON object in good time complexity?

Tags: c#, json, data-structures

I have a JSON object that has the potential to be nested several times like so:

```
{
"type": "cars",
"nested1": {
    "nested2": {
        "name": "tesla",
        "nested3": {
            "name": "audi",
            "make": "q7",
            "nested4": {}
                   }
               }
           }
}
```

I want to be able to go through each field, check if it contains an object as its value and then if that's the case, go inside this nested, and check for fields that contain an object as its value and so on...

I've tried trivial approach but the time complexity gets really bad. For 3 nested objects, its O(n^3), as you have to traverse each field in each nested object.

Is there any datastructure that could give me a better time complexity?

Comment: When you say it is O(N³) what is N? It looks like it is O(N) when N is the number of properties, which is going to be the best possible, unless you already know whether a property contains an object you are going to have to visit every property.

Comment: If N is the number of properties, then if we go through the nested and then again through the nested don't we get O(N * M * K), if they each have different number of properties? I just wrote N^3 for simplicity

Comment: You said you try something. It may be interresting to had a try into the question. 
So we can understand where your not standart definition of "O(3^n)" came from. 
It will be nice to also have a complete Json here. I will assume that nested4 is just an object null alway with not properties. 
Perhaps you can also think the over way around: What do you expect if you had to design without the json what will the expected datastructure look like?

And bny the way have you try to past the json in anytool that auto generate the class or are you doing `JObject`, `JArray` parsing?

Comment: As your requirements, Since we need to visit every node (property) and we are visiting every node only once, it is not `O(N³)` rather `O(N)`. You can use recursion, dictionary or any other approach, complexity it will remain same, `O(N)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is some other information used, the scan will be O(Nₚ) where Nₚ is the number of properties.

In your example, the top level object has 2 properties, the next level 1, the next level 2, the third level 3 and the final level 0. You need to visit 8 properties, 2+1+2+3+0.
Although 8 happens to be 2³, this doesn't make the algorithm O(N³) for any useful N, as that relationship will break if you have an example with differing numbers of properties or more or less than three levels of populated objects. It is normal to chose an N which is representative of the problem. If you serialised the JSON to a file with no extra whitespace, finding the empty object would become a substring search for '{}', you are not going to improve on O(N) for a substring search.

The only way you are going to improve the algorithm is to use some extra information to avoid visiting every property; for example if you know that empty objects only occur in the fourth level then you don't need to look at properties in objects at that level or deeper.

Comment: Considering that JSON is just a piece of text, the normal deserialization method would read all characters, so `N` would represent the number of characters not properties. The properties themselves can be verified via a hashmap/dictionary, which is `O(1)` for each property, so total `O(Nc + Np)` I think. Performance could perhaps be increased by early-bail-out and not verifying closing brackets etc, not sure how that works out.